# cv2.stereocalibrate() error about "cameraMatrix" not being a numerical tuple

Tags: python, opencv, camera, calibration

I'm working on estimating distance from stereo cameras. I  am using python 2.7.11 and OpenCV 3.1 versions.I calibrated every camera separately and found intrinsic parameters. the problem is that when I use cv2.stereocalibtare() function in the way stated in OpenCV documents I get the error: "TypeError: cameraMatrix1 is not a numerical tuple".

the code looks like this :

```
stereo_criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS, 100, 1e-5)
ret_stereo, R, T, E, F = cv2.stereoCalibrate(objpointsL, imgpointsL, imgpointsR, grayL.shape[::-1],mtxL, distcoeffL, mtxR, distcoeffR, criteria=stereo_criteria, flags=cv2.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC)
```

I thought that changing the camera matrix into tuple using tuple() function  might work. it didn't change anything. and then I thought the problem might be the version of opencv  that I'm using so I changed it into 2.4.13 but that didn't change anything also. after all these tries I thought I let the stereocalibrate() do the camera matrix and distortion coefficient estimation itself without any single camera calibration.

the code looked like this:

```
stereo_criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS, 100, 1e-5)
stereocalib_retval, cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, R, T, E, F = cv2.stereoCalibrate(objpointsL,imgpointsL,imgpointsR,grayL.shape, criteria=stereo_criteria)
```

but it gets an error saying: "TypeError: Required argument 'distCoeffs1' (pos 5) not found"
I just can't figure out why this function is not working. All I want is to calculate the R, T, E, F values

**UPDATE:** For the last error I tried this:

```
stereocalib_retval, cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, R, T, E, F = cv2.stereoCalibrate(objpointsL,
                                                                                                         imgpointsL,
                                                                                                         imgpointsR,
                                                                                                         mtxL,
                                                                                                         distcoeffL,
                                                                                                         mtxR,
                                                                                                         distcoeffR,
                                                                                                         image_size,
                                                                                                         criteria=stereocalib_criteria,
                                                                                                         flags=stereocalib_flags)
```

and it worked. although putting cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2 were not needed ( and are actually equal to mtxL,discoeffL,mtxR,discoeffR respectively ) omitting them was causing error for me. The first problem still remains.

I appreciate your help

Masood Saber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the version issue I guess. I have the same issue when I use Opencv 3.3.1, but it solved when I changed to 2.4.13.